# Turn each element of a list into a separate string?

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

I have the following list:

`mylist=[[3, 95],[8, 92],[18, 25],[75, 78],[71, 84],-9999,[96, 50],[91, 70],-9999,[19, 60]]`

In it, each element is a list itself, apart from the `-9999` values which are `int` values.

Say that I want to use a `for` loop to transform each element into a `string`, in order to write it to an `excel` or `csv` file. How could I do it?

Here is my attempt:

```
mylist=[[3, 95],[8, 92],[18, 25],[75, 78],[71, 84],-9999,[96, 50],[91, 70],-9999,[19, 60]]
for i in enumerate(mylist):
    str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in mylist)
```

But what I get is the entire list transformed into a single string, without each item being differentiated:

`str1='[3, 95][8, 92][18, 25][75, 78][71, 84]-9999[96, 50][91, 70]-9999[19, 60]'`

Instead, I would like this:

```
str1='[3,95]' #Iter 1
str1='[8, 92]' #Iter 2
str1='[18, 25]' #Iter 3
...
#and so forth
```

Comment: Have a look at 'list comprehensions', https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Just don't `''.join()` it.

Comment: `for i in mylist:`
    `print i`
Then convert into string

Comment: `'\n'.join(str(e) for e in mylist)` should do it

Comment: Do you want this `[str(i) for i in mylist]`

Comment: @AkshayHazari How do you write this inside a for loop?

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary Nope. This is your output: `'[3, 95]\n[8, 92]\n[18, 25]\n[75, 78]\n[71, 84]\n-9999\n[96, 50]\n[91, 70]\n-9999\n[19, 60]'`.

Comment: @FC84 .You could directly use that instead of a for loop . It is called a list comprehension

Comment: @AkshayHazari I don't think it works this way. If I add your hint inside my loop, I expect `'[19, 60]'`, as this is the last iteration. Instead, I get `type(str1) -> list`. This is not what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
for e in map(str, myList):
    #do your stuff here, e is '[3, 95]' on the fst element and so on
```

`map` applies a function to each element in `myList`. Using the `str` function will transform each element in your list in a string so you can use it freely.

Answer (score 2):

```
mylist = [[3, 95],[8, 92],[18, 25],[75, 78],[71, 84],-9999,[96, 50],[91, 70],-9999,[19, 60]]

# convert all elements
new_list = [str(e) for e in mylist ]

# use it
for str1 in new_list:
    print str1
```

or

```
mylist = [[3, 95],[8, 92],[18, 25],[75, 78],[71, 84],-9999,[96, 50],[91, 70],-9999,[19, 60]]

for x in mylist:
    # convert one element and use it
    str1 = str(x) 
    print str1
```

Answer (score 1):

You've made two separate mistakes here. First, inside each iteration you're using `str.join` which makes a string from the full list, when you just want `str(elem)` where `elem` is the current item in the list.

```
mylist=[[3, 95],[8, 92],[18, 25],[75, 78],[71, 84],-9999,[96, 50],[91, 70],-9999,[19, 60]]
for elem in mylist:
    str1 = str(elem)
```

You also used `enumerate` improperly. `enumerate` is used to get the index value alongside each item of a list. Your original code took the index and the item both as `i`. ie. `i = (0, [3, 95])`, when really you'd want them separate. If you need these indices, use this:

```
for i, elem in enumerate(mylist):
    str1 = str(elem)
```

Where `i = 0` and `elem = [3, 95]`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Precise and concise answer. Also, thanks for pointing out my mistakes.

Comment: @FC84 Glad to help, I'd actually recommend Daniel's approach over mine if you don't need `enumerate`, as using map saves you a line of code and looks cleaner.